# Unit Testing Flask-Admin modules?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I was wondering, is there any way to test a given defined BaseView? can I just integrate it with the Flask testing facilities? I had been looking around and I couldn't find anything about unit testing Flask-Admin views.

I will appreciate any guidance.